# How do I obtain the count of corner points in a matrix as well as store their positions in an array?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was told that the coordinates of a matrix must not necessarily be represented using the centre points, but could also be represented using the corner points. I however really can’t figure out how to go about this.  Nonetheless, I have this information that relates the matrix notations for both the centre and corner points as shown below.

[image]

```
[Nr, Nc] = size(Img);
```

And:

`Nr = ny+1;   % which is total no. of centre rows
 Nc = nx+1;   % which is total no. of center columns`

Also,

`ny = Nr – 1;   % which is total no. of line rows
 nx = Nc – 1;   % which is total no. of line columns`

`T = ny * nx;   % where T = Total no. of internal nodes
nodeCount = nx(iy – 1) + jx;`

The count order is row-by-row i.e. beginning from the nodes: `(1,1) to (1,nx)` and then `(2,1) to (2, nx)`, etc. Note that in the given image (6x6 matrix), nodeCount has 25 array elements.

Now, I need to obtain nodeCount such that it contains an array of all counted internal nodes from 1 to T in the count order specified. I would then obtain the x and y coordinates from each index in nodeCount.

Please, i need help/suggestions/advice on how I could resolve this. Many thanks.

Comment: Your description is a little vague, is `[x,y] = meshgrid(1:nx,1:ny); coords = [x(:),y(:)]` what you need?

Comment: Thank you so much @Florian. Apologies for replying so late. Yes, your code gets me the `x and y coords`  which is the 2nd part of the question. I however will still need to find `nodeCount`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The way you write it, the nodeCount should be `nodeCount  = nx*(coords(:,2)-1) + coords(:,1)`, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I do get the nodeCount from that, but from the way the entire code works, i will need to have nodeCounts and then extract the x and y coords from nodeCount for further computations. I hope you get what i mean?

Comment: I hope I got what you mean: I made a reply showing all 4 variants: creating `nodeCount` and `coords` from scratch and converting one into the other. The last one you asked is number 4): converting nodeCount to coords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the discussion in the comments got a little long, I decided for an answer:

1) Create coords (from scratch)

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:nx,1:ny); 
coords = [x(:),y(:)];
```

2) Create nodeCount (from scratch)

```
nodeCount = reshape(reshape((1:nx*ny),nx,ny)',nx*ny,[]);
```

3) Convert coords to nodeCount

```
nodeCount = nx*(coords(:,2)-1) + coords(:,1);
```

4) Convert nodeCount to coords

```
coords_x = mod(nodeCount-1,nx) + 1;
coords_y = (nodeCount - coords_x)/nx + 1;
coords = [coords_x, coords_y];
```

**edit**: Of course, 3-D works as well. Depends on how you count your nodes then. One way is this (untested but I guess you get the idea):

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:nx,1:ny,1:nz);
coords = [x(:),y(:),z(:)];
nodeCount = ny*nx*(coords(:,3)-1) + nx*(coords(:,2)-1) + coords(:,1)
coords_x = mod(nodeCount-1,nx) + 1;
coords_y = mod((nodeCount - coords_x)/nx, ny) + 1;
coords_z = (nodeCount - coords_x - nx*(coords_y-1))/nx/ny + 1;
```

Comment: Perfect!. Thank you so so much!

Comment: Just a thought... i am wondering if and the possibility of getting a 3rd dimension into this. Any ideas how i could get the nodeCount and its coords?

Comment: Oh! thanks very much. Will check this out in no time and will let you know. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Florian. Please can i possibly chat with you privately?

Comment: Hmm, if you promise you will not send me your code to check it, then okay. ;-)