# How do I obtain node counts correctly from meshgrid?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Assuming I have the following vectors:

```
x = [1 2 3 4];
y = [4 5 6];
z = [7 8 9];
```

I want to merge these into grids and then obtain the x,y,z coordinates as well as nodeCount. I have the code From:  [How do I obtain the count of corner points in a matrix as well as store their positions in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006540/how-do-i-obtain-the-count-of-corner-points-in-a-matrix-as-well-as-store-their-po/42139617?noredirect=1#comment71670079_42139617)

As follows:

```
ny = length(y) - 1;
nx = length(x) - 1;
nz = length(z) - 1;

%# Obtain grid vectors
[ygv, xgv, zgv] = meshgrid(1:ny, 1:nx, 1:nz); 
coords = [ygv(:), xgv(:), zgv(:)]

%# Obtain node counts
nodeCount = ny*nx*(coords(:,3) - 1) + nx*(coords(:,2) - 1) + coords(:,1)

%# Obtain coordinates
x_coord = mod(nodeCount - 1, nx) + 1;
y_coord = mod((nodeCount - x_coord)/nx, ny) + 1;
z_coord = (nodeCount - x_coord - nx*(y_coord - 1))/nx/ny + 1;
```

My expected result would be:

```
coords = [1 1 1 
         1 2 1 
         1 3 1 
         2 1 1
         2 2 1
         2 3 1
         1 1 2
         1 2 2
         1 3 2
         2 1 2
         2 2 2
         2 3 2]

nodeCount = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12]

y_coord = [1;1;1;2;2;2;1;1;1;2;2;2]
x_coord = [1;2;3;1;2;3;1;2;3;1;2;3]
z_coord = [1;1;1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;2;2]
```

However, the code only returns correct results for `cords, ygv, xgv, and zgv`, but not for the rest. I understand the `nodeCount` counts the no. of rows in `coords`. In any case, I suspect that the `nodeCount` formula is probably wrong, which then affects the subsequent computations. Please is there a way to get the `nodeCount` as expected? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Oops! i just figured out the error had to do with my ordering of coordinates. The correct nodeCount formula considering the ordering of y,x,z should be:

```
nodeCount = ny*nx*(coords(:,3) - 1) + nx*(coords(:,1) - 1) + coords(:,2)
```

With that, every other thing works.